# Help in analysing circuit to show which resistor controls the differential gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential, summing, summer

I understand the circuit to be a summing circuit but I am struggling to analyse past this point: Vout = R5 (((-R2/R1 * V2)/R4) * (V1 / R3)). can anyone analyse this further to prove that R5 is the controlling resistor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkR6MX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So, what is your precise question?

Comment: I need help in proving which resistor controls the gain of the whole circuit

Comment: That's still a statement, and not a question! I know this really sounds like nitpicking, but since this is clearly a homework-style assignment, we'd really need to know what you've considered so far to be able to help you– and we **really** need you to ask a question to have something specific to answer.

Comment: (it helps when you add that to the question instead of as a comment - this is crucial!)

Comment: Forget equations for a second and think about what you're looking at. OA1, R1 and R2 are a inverting amplifier. Next you have a summing amplifier which adds V1 and the output from the last opamp. If you only had the OA1 circuit, and I asked you which resistor set the gain what would you say? If I asked the same question for just OA2, what would you say? Now ignore OA1, redraw the circuit with just Vx and V1. What resistor sets the gain then?